# Find a view dependency at any db

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dependencies, view

I'm in the middle of cleaning some servers. So currently this is my server (sorry for the lame diagram):

```
DatabaseServer00
 -DatabaseA
   -ViewA
   -ViewB
   -ViewC
 -DatabaseB 
 -DatabaseC
```

I need to find if there is any sp/triger/function/etc... in DatabaseB/C that calls ViewA from DatabaseA.

I know that i can find dependencies in DatabaseA with this sp_depends
And I'm currently using this to search in other DB

```
    Declare @Query varchar(max)
    SET @Query = 'SELECT DISTINCT o.name AS Object_Name,o.type_desc FROM
    sys.sql_modules m INNER JOIN sys.objects  o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
    WHERE m.definition like ''%ViewA%''' 
    EXEC sp _MSforeachdb @Query
```

But.... This code right here ^ does not returns me that ViewB depends on ViewC

So i'm kind of out of queries to run. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not sure if I got the question. Do you want to catch Inter-Database calls or any VIEW requests?

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are having a problem with. I hope you don't have nested views though as the performance if horrendous.

Comment: *I'm currently using this to search in other DB* - Not clear. Shouldn't you be using `sp_depends` on `DatabaseA` where the `ViewB` and `ViewC` reside?

Comment: @SlavaMurygin inter-database you mean like DatabaseServer00.dbo.viewA fragments... yeah that's what i'm looking for.

Comment: @Think2ceCode1ce if that were the case yes. but i want to look for stored procedures in `DatabaseB` and `DatabaseC` where `ViewB` and `ViewC` are being used

Comment: @SeanLange i want to find calls to `ViewA` `ViewB` and `ViewC` in databases `DatabaseB` and `DatabaseC`.  Views B and C are returned with `sp_depends` but are not returned with the query I posted

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Information Schema Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx), they should be able to help you in most cases except the Triggers, which you'll probably have to rely on sys.triggers

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.routines ISR
WHERE CHARINDEX('dbo.ViewA', ISR.ROUTINE_DEFINITION) > 0

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS ISW
WHERE CHARINDEX('dbo.ViewA', ISW.VIEW_DEFINITION) > 0

SELECT 
    DB_NAME() AS DatabasName
    , so.name as TableName
    , tr.name as TriggerName
    , sc.text as TriggerText
     FROM sys.triggers tr
    INNER JOIN sys.objects so
    ON tr.parent_id = so.object_id
    INNER JOIN syscomments sc
        ON sc.id = tr.object_id
    WHERE CHARINDEX('dbo.ViewA', sc.text) > 0
```

Comment: Thank for the help. I'm running the query you shared with me. but i'm getting no result. Even with the whole `DatabaseA.dbo.ViewA` declaration i get nothing. Am i doing somthing wrong.

Comment: Some of that may depend upon the naming convention used in the definitions, i.e. I always use schema_name.object_name, but your database may only use object_name(i.e. ViewA and not dbo.ViewA).  Are you running the queries against each database individually?

Comment: Yep, I'm going one by one but every dataset is empty